# how to show img tags in a webview?

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview, webviewclient

I am receiving data from server and its basiclay html conetnt with spans and img tags.

here it is:

```
<p><em>בדיקה לא למחוק</em></p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                                                    <p><u>בדיקה לא למחוק</u></p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                                                    <p><strong>בדיקה לא למחוק</strong><img src="http://images1.ynet.co.il/PicServer5/2017/12/29/8247918/824791601000100980734no.jpg" /></p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                                                    <p><img src="https://images1.ynet.co.il/PicServer5/2017/12/29/8247918/824791601000100980734no.jpg" /></p>

                                                                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

in order to load the data in webview i did this:

```
 mWebViewMainContent = view.findViewById(R.id.webview_article_content);
    WebSettings settings = mWebViewMainContent.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //// TODO: 28/12/2017 handle languages
    sb.append("<HTML dir=\"rtl\" ><HEAD><LINK href=\"theCss.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body style=\"direction:rtl ;\" > ");
    sb.append("<div  class=\"article-page\"><p>");
    sb.append(Html.fromHtml((String) article.getMain()).toString());
    sb.append("</p></div>");
    sb.append("</body></HTML>");

    mWebViewMainContent.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

i succeeded to show the content in the web view but there is no spans and the images url not loading ? 
why is that ?

can somebody show me an example of what im missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

try to debug your webview with chrome:

1. webview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
2. open chrome with url: `chrome://inspect/#devices` on your computer
3. run your app on your device and open the Activity which contains your WebView
4. connect your device to computer
5. you can debug your html code with chrome now!

Comment: thnk you , i idid this and i found out that there is no img tags , it seems that sb.append(Html.fromHtml((String) article.getMain()).toString()) remove the tag img .. see my own answer below for what  i did :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved and here is the code :

```
    mWebViewMainContent = view.findViewById(R.id.webview_article_content);
    WebSettings settings = mWebViewMainContent.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //// TODO: 28/12/2017 handle languages
    sb.append("<HTML dir=\"rtl\" ><HEAD><LINK href=\"theCss.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"/></HEAD><body style=\"direction:rtl ;\" > ");
    sb.append(article.getMain());
    sb.append("</body></HTML>");

    mWebViewMainContent.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true) ;
    mWebViewMainContent.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/" , "<style>img{display: inline;height: auto;max-width: 100%;}</style>"+ sb.toString(), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```